# Help to pick out sound system for an open air cinema

Tags: sound, cinema

I'm going to make an open air cinema. The count of guests would be 50-60 people. what kind of sound system would you suggest ?

Comment: This is pretty open-ended. At a bare minimum we would need to know what kind of budget you are thinking of. Keep in mind you need more power outdoors than indoors since you have fewer or no walls to reflect any of the sound back into the listening area.

Comment: Hi Todd,
My budget is very limited. All I can spend for sound system is 1K $ no more.

At the place where i'm going to build my small business there are no walls. It's open space at sixth floor. 

The count of audience is 50 people.

Comment: So is there a ceiling? Is weather a factor (rain, wind, sand, etc.)?

Comment: The cinema will work only in summer. Yes, it does not insure from rain ( in wind we can't work ). For a rainy day I'll build self covering ceiling that will insure the audience from rain.